# How to make full screen in Android 4.0

Tags: android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Android 4.0 phones only have virtual buttons, which actually go invisible when playing youtube/video at fullscreen (the video portion takes over where the buttons are).

I want to do this, but haven't found a way.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

or

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

do not cover the virtual buttons.

Here is an example that shows the type of full screen I'm talking about:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lw_O1JpmPns

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I added this `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` flag to my video activity and that hid the virtual buttons.

```
WebView view = new WebView(this);
view.setSystemUiVisibility(WebView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Another choice is to use the `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE` flag. This doesn't hide the buttons though. Instead it makes the buttons go to "Low Profile" mode (basically turns them into little dots)

Answer (score 2):

This works on my device but not in the emulator. Add this tho your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
    <activity ...
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the onCreate() of your Activity, add this:

```cs
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
this.getWindow().getDecorView()
    .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Worked well for me (but is not Honeycomb-compatible).

Answer (score 1):

To make the buttons completely invisible, you should do

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
this.getWindow().getDecorView()
        .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION 
               | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

The buttons would not use any space on the screen, unless you swipe up from the bottom of the screen. Notice that you need to target at SDK version 19 for this to work.